# How to find out current age in Python from a certain date?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using the current Python and am having a hard time finding any similar code on the internet to print out an age based off of a certain date. Such as if I was born in 1994 I would be 25.

Edit: Date format: 1994/4/7  Not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: What is the date format? please share that here. If its only calculating age from year then it shouldn't be hard

Comment: Date format: 1994/4/7 Not sure if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You may enforce the user to enter the date in a specific format like:

```
from datetime import date
date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format')
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
dob = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

`OR`

Ask the user to enter the 3 parts of a date separately, and format into  date:

```
from datetime import date
year = int(input('Enter a year'))
month = int(input('Enter a month'))
day = int(input('Enter a day'))
dob = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

And then after you can calculate the age:

```
def calculateAge(birthDate): 
    today = date.today() 
    age = today.year - birthDate.year - 
         ((today.month, today.day) < 
         (birthDate.month, birthDate.day)) 

    return age
print (calculateAge(dob))
```